# Reqex pattern that returns html tags around specified string

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have been trying to make regex pattern which will return the most inner html tag with specific string sequence within razor. Note that I am not very experienced with regex.

Lets have basic cshtml structure which is input to `Regex.Match`

```
@{
    <div id="Base">
        <div id="MainDiv">
            <span id="HeaderSpan">
                Header
            </span>

            TestText1
        </div>
        @{
             var innerRazorVariable = "test"
         }
    </div>

    var razorVariable = "test";
}
```

I am looking for pattern that will return this string if "Header" is SpecifiedString

```
<span id="HeaderSpan">
    Header
</span>
```

I have managed to write pattern that will retun content of most inner razor that contains specified string with

```
Regex.Match(source, "@{.*(@{.*?" + SpecifiedString + ".*?})|.*}");
```

That works fine. If `Match` contains `group`, then that `group` is the most inner razor delaration and its content. If not that the `Value` of `Match` is the most inner razor and its content.

Problem is with the most inner html tags. I have tried to make write it similiar as Razor Regex but without success. Closest i get was with

```
(<.*?>).*SpecifiedString .*(<\/.*?>)
```

[Online Regex](https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/476)

I know why it is not working as i wish, but i cant figure out what should i change.

Second solution i tried was with

```
(?'html'<.*?>)|(SpecifiedString)
```

[Online Regex](https://regex101.com/r/DS408A/1/)

Then I was trying to find the most inner html marks with foreach over groups and captures, but i couldnt get it working so i dropped it.

> Edit.

Additional info. If Specified Text is not in any html tags regex should not return anything. I am trying to find out if specified string is html or c# code in razor.

My question.

Is it even possible to write regex pattern like that, if yes how?

Comment: "If Specified Text is not in any html tags"? It will always be inside the <body> tag.

Comment: Yea, but input for `Regex.Match` is only content of razor, like in example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[Don't use Regex to handle HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4519059)**

But I think you can use a better regex like this:

```
<[^>]+>\s*Header\s*<[^>]+>
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/477)

Explanation:

```
<[^>]+>    start with '<' followed by non-'>' characters and end with '>'
\s*        zero or many of whitespace characters
```

Note: using `.*` is so general in regex when you can make more specification don't ignore it.

Comment: I also think a lot, but many times it does not work. Would you mind explaining why this works?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I add some more information to make more sense, But mind that a tag is always start with `<` followed by any other characters except `>` then finished by `>` -HTH ;).

Comment: Thats works nice, but i have failed to describe another situation. I have made edit in question.

Comment: People do not know HTML enough. The Regex does not work in valid HTML cases: https://regex101.com/r/A3bHxF/1

Comment: @ThomasWeller https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4519059

Comment: Exactly. That's the true answer. I would have closed it as duplicate. Or suggest HtmlAgilityPack as an answer.

Comment: Very well then, ill look up for some solution with XML parser. Thanks for help.